# mysql joins with a master table

Tags: mysql

I have a table named
**menu** with columns

```
menu_id,menu_name,system_id,filename
```

another table with the **menu_users** 
with fields

```
menu_user_id,menu_id
```

Another table named 
**system**

```
system_id,system_name
```

I want to join all the three table to get columns from the menutable and systemname from the system table

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM menu, menu_users, System 
WHERE menu.menu_id=menu_users.menu_id 
AND menu.system_id=System.system_id
```

But I'm not able to get the desired result.

Please help me

Comment: What result do you want? What result do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to join, it's better to use a JOIN command:

```
SELECT * 
FROM menu
INNER JOIN menu_users ON menu.menu_id=menu_users.menu_id
INNER JOIN System ON menu.system_id=System.system_id
```

That being said, you don't need backticks like you had.

Last but not least, DON'T use `SELECT *` in any query. Ask for the columns you need only.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to join the table first and then specify on what condition.

Something like:

select * from table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 INNER JOIN table_3 where table_1.ID = table_2.ID AND table_2.ID = table_3.ID

Hope this helps!

Comment: Be careful, `INNER JOIN`s require an `ON` clause (or `USING`) : http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/join/ansi_inner_join.html

Comment: @MPelletier - I did not know what joins he needed so i just mentioned the INNER JOIN. But you are correct on the ON clause. thanks for the heads up!